# Visual Studio - Stuck on Loading/Initializing Solution after installing Xamarin.Auth Nuget Package

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, nuget

I just installed the Xamarin.Auth nuget package and since then my project has been taking forever to load/initialize each time .

I tried earlier versions without that package and they load almost instantly .

Anyone faced this issue before and any idea how to fix it ?

I tried using my older versions and setting up the package again but then same thing happens .

It takes a long time , sometimes not responding ...but eventually , after a while - it loads (5-20mins every time)

Note : I downloaded and tied this sample project and the same things happens with this one , so its definitely those packages causing the issue :

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoAWSAuth/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/oauth/

If anyone can try it and it works well - it might be my VS settings

Answer (score 0):

The sample project with Xamarin.Auth nuget package installed working fine on my VS2015 Update 3 with NuGet Package Manager 3.4.4 installed.

And following is my VS Settings for NuGet Package. Please check your VS Settings for NuGet Packages.
[image]

In addition, please open the nuget.org site in your browser directly to check whether this site could be opened in browser quickly. If it open slowly, it means the issue caused by your network when restoring nuget packages from nuget.org site.